# Effective implementation of conversion small string to uint64_t

Tags: c++11, char

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T>
T oph_(const char *s){
    constexpr std::size_t MAX = sizeof(T);
    const     std::size_t size = strnlen(s, MAX);

    T r = 0;

    for(auto it = s; it - s < size; ++it)
        r = r << 8 | *it;

    return r;
}

inline uint64_t oph(const char *s){
    return oph_<uint64_t>(s);
}

int main(){
    uint64_t const a = oph("New York City");
    uint64_t const b = oph("Boston International");
    return a > b;
}
```

I want to convert first 8 characters from `const char *` to `uint64_t` so I can easily compare if two strings are greater / lesser.

I am aware that equals will semi-work.

However I am not sure if this is most efficient implementation.

I want the implementation to work on both little and big endian machines.

Comment: I would worry more about `strnlen` in your code. If you are doing sequential search already, you can just copy data in a loop byte per byte.
Just swap bytes afterwards on BE machine using cpu-specific instruction. It should be the fastest way of doing this. If don't need to find string length, you can try to do more.

Comment: `strlen` is highly optimized, I would not worry about it, but I think you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a C implementation, that should be faster that your implementation, but I still need to use `strncpy` which should be the bottleneck

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <byteswap.h>

union small_str {
    uint64_t v;
    char buf[8];
};

static uint64_t fill_small_str(const char *str)
{
    union small_str ss = { 0 };

    strncpy(ss.buf, str, 8);
#if defined(__BYTE_ORDER__) && (__BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__)
    return ss.v;
#else
    return bswap_64(ss.v);
#endif
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t const a = fill_small_str("Aew York City");
    uint64_t const b = fill_small_str("Boston International");
    printf("%lu ; %lu ; %d\n", a, b, (a < b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nick A big warning about the big endian detection, these macro are a gcc specific feature. But really most of the cpu are little endian.

Comment: In my project I already use endian.h so I made it using `htobe64`.

Comment: generated assembly looks very small (y)

Comment: One comment - Due to problems with string comparison, I was unable to make successful string to uint64_t conversion, but I end up with this one. Assuming I did it correctly, speed up of my application is 50%.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179118/cache-friendly-string